# SCSS dynamically create exact contrast colour

Tags: colors, sass

I would like some help figuring out a routine for creating from a base colour the exact contrasting colour.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sass has a variety of color functions which may be what you're looking for.

Complement: 180° around the color wheel.

```
div { color: complement($color); }
```

Invert: Reverses the RGB values, but doesn't adjust the opacity.

```
div { color: invert($color); }
```

For more color functions, see http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html or [examples on Codepen.](http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/hbqsB)